# Access Request Data NSUrlProtocol with SessionClient

Tags: nsurl, nsurlrequest, afnetworking-2, rubymotion, nsurlsession

I'm having trouble intercepting SessionClient post requests using AFMotion SessionClient. Weirdly, my code works fine when using a generic AFMotion::HTTP.post action

```
class Protocol < NSURLProtocol

  def self.canInitWithRequest(request)
    return true
  end

  def initWithRequest(request, cachedResponse:response, client: client)
    puts request.HTTPBody
  end
end

NSURLProtocol.registerClass(Protocol)

# this works fine for intercepting data
AFMotion::HTTP.post("http://espn.com", {:msg => "I like sports"}) do
  # the above will output msg="I like sports as expected"
end

# this doesn't work as expected
c = AFMotion::SessionClient.build "http://www.espn.com"
c.post("/", {:msg => "I like sports"} do 
  # the initWithRequest request object has nil for both the HTTPBodyStream and HTTPBody methods
end
```

Here's what I'm working on. The request parameter that is sent to initWithRequest doesn't seem to have access to the post data, when using a SessionClient, it does, however work fine and have access to the expected parameters when using a generic AFMotion::HTTP.post

Comment: Not really answering the question, but you could look into AFNetworkActivityLogger pod. It will log all network traffic for you after calling AFNetworkActivityLogger.startLogging